# Check convergence of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to check the convergence of the following series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left (\frac{3+n^3}{4-n+n^2-3n^3}\right )^n \ \\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left (\frac{3+n^2}{4+2n^2}\right )^n \\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left (\sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{n}\right )  $$

I have done the following :
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left (\frac{3+n^3}{4-n+n^2-3n^3}\right )^n \rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left |\frac{3+n^3}{4-n+n^2-3n^3}\right |=\left |-\frac{1}{3}\right |=\frac{1}{3}<1 \text{ Convergence } \\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left (\frac{3+n^2}{4+2n^2}\right )^n \rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left |\frac{3+n^2}{4+2n^2}\right |=\frac{1}{2}<1 \text{ Convergence }\\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left (\sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{n}\right ) \rightarrow \sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{n} = \sqrt{2}\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n} =(\sqrt{2}-1)\cdot \sqrt{n} \geq \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{n} \\ \text{ since the series of } \sqrt{n} \text{ diverges we get that also the original series diverges}$$ Is everything correct ?

Comment: Looks good. To add I would reference that the first two were concluded by the “Root test” and the latter by “Comparison”.

Comment: Great!! So the bound that I took at the latter to compare is the correct one or would you suggest an other one? @ChrisChristopherson

Comment: I like what you said. $$\sqrt{2}-1\approx .414 \geqslant 1/4$$

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! :-) @ChrisChristopherson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit of the general term is,  after your work,  $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt2-1)\sqrt n=\infty$.

Thus since it doesn't go to zero,  the series diverges (sometimes called the divergence test).

Comment: Thank you!! :-)